# Usepackage, babel,polish,french,germany

Tags: babel, input-encodings

This is my first time in latex editor. I'm using texmaker + miktex 2.9 and i have problem with first document.

I tried do something like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french,german,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

śśś

\end{document}
```

And it doesn't work with polish letters, why?
Instead of "śśś" i got somekind of weird signs.
I installed babel package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Things look alright if you change the option of the `inputenc` package from `cp1250` to `utf8`.

Comment: Depending on how your editor is set up, you need to tell LaTeX the right option for package `inputenc`. Most modern editors use `utf8` per default.

Comment: Thx for help, it works ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a wrong input encoding of the file

Comment: Right, this helped me so maybe someday help someone else. Put one of the comments as answer and i will accept it ;)